# Date Time Conversion in SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, utc

I'm currently working on a report where PST (Pacific Standard Time) was used as the basis of the dates.

I noticed that sometimes when I retrieve data on specific dates there are missing columns.

I found out that the database time/server time was using UTC while the report is using PST/Localtime.

In the code behind section of the code this is the default date that they are using if no choice was selected.

```
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        FromTB.Text = DateTime.Today.ToLocalTime().ToString("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm tt");
        ToTB.Text = DateTime.Today.ToLocalTime().AddMinutes(1439).ToString("dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm tt");
    }
```

Below is the code in the front used on retrieving data in the database.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource1" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:xxxxx %>' SelectCommand="select StudYear ,count(CAST(CreatedDate as DATE)) AS StudCount
from Student 
where CreatedDate >= @CreatedDate and CreatedDate <= @CreatedDate2 and StudYear is not null
group by StudYear
order by StudYear"

 <SelectParameters>
  <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="FromTB" Name="CreatedDate" PropertyName="Text" Type="DateTime" />
  <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ToTB" Name="CreatedDate2" PropertyName="Text" Type="DateTime" />
 </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Now when I save the data example today. The data inserted was created on "2020-03-09 04:00:25.940" UTC while the report page defaults the date to PST "Sunday, March 08, 2020 12:00 AM" to "Sunday, March 08, 2020 11:59 PM".

Because of this I cannot retrieve the newly created user.

How do I convert the `@CreatedDate` and `@CreatedDate2` in the `SqlDataSource` to UTC to get the data from the database? Or what should be the right approach to get the correct information?

Comment: By the way, if you want all results for a given day, it's probably better to use something like: `date >= 2020-03-09T00:00:00Z && date < 2020-03-10T00:00:00Z` (i.e. greater than or equal to the start of today, less than the start of tomorrow) rather than your current approach which wouldn't include anything beyond `2020-03-09T23:59:00`.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for your feedback john.